# jooq timestamp arithmetic Cannot convert from Integer to LocalDateTime

Tags: jooq

With jooq 3.13.x, we are using

```
Field<Instant> midPointDueTime = TICKET.READY.plus(TICKET.DUE.minus(TICKET.READY).div(2));
```

where READY and DUE fields are of type java.time.Instant. They are DATETIME fields in the database (normally java.sql.Timestamp) but are converted to Instant with a javax.persistence.AttributeConverter. The database in question is Informix, but we are using the open source version of jooq for now with the DEFAULT dialect and trying to avoid cases where things would deviate from standard SQL syntax.

From that field declaration jooq 3.13.x creates the following SQL snippet which works as expected

```
TICKET.READY + ((TICKET.DUE - TICKET.READY) / 2))
```

This is the expected DATETIME arithmetic. We are looking for a timestamp halfway between READY and DUE.

But jooq 3.14 or 3.15 both throw a runtime exception.

> org.jooq.exception.DataTypeException: Cannot convert from 2 (class java.lang.Integer) to class java.time.LocalDateTime

No SQL is generated, so I don't think this is an Informix compatibility issue. The error happens before any SQL statement is logged.

Is this possibly a bug, or is there something else I can do to achieve the same date arithmetic result?

Comment: *"The error happens before any SQL statement is logged."* - If you think it's a bug, please report one here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose

Comment: Reported: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12544

Answer (score 0):

#### Regarding dialects

From the [`SQLDialect.DEFAULT`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/SQLDialect.html#DEFAULT) javadoc:

> This dialect is chosen in the absence of a more explicit dialect. It is not intended to be used with any actual database as it may combine dialect-specific things from various dialects.

The purpose of this dialect is to be used in cases where no other dialect is available, and debug log information is needed, e.g. when writing:

```java
DSL.abs(1).toString(); // This uses DEFAULT to render the abs(1) function call
```

You shouldn't use this dialect in any production situation, its behaviour may change at any time for various reasons. It's certainly not integration tested with any RDBMS. Use the [`SQLDialect.INFORMIX`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/SQLDialect.html#INFORMIX) dialect instead

#### After further research

Thanks to your detailed bug report hree: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12544, it can be seen that this is a regression that will be fixed in jOOQ 3.16.0 and 3.15.4